# In installing / updating r packages I am getting namespace error, Permission Denied error etc

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am new in R and my `tidymodels` have been giving me `issues` lately so from one of stckoverflow post I got to know about updating "tune" packages from `github` but this was giving issues so I reinstalled `rtools`.

1. I have reinstalled `rtools`, have set `path variables`.

**Issues**

2. Now whenever I try `devtools::install_github("tidymodels/tune")` I get error `Error: package ‘digest’ does not have a namespace`.
3. I have tried reinstalling `rlang` and there I get `Permission denied`: `problem copying C:\R\R-4.0.3\library\00LOCK\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to C:\R\R-4.0.3\library\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied`
4. As in another post I read about reinstalling `glue` I get `Permission denied` for same as well:  `problem copying C:\R\R-4.0.3\library\00LOCK\glue\libs\x64\glue.dll to C:\R\R-4.0.3\library\glue\libs\x64\glue.dll: Permission denied Warning in install.packages : restored ‘glue’`

Is this normal with R or do I need to fix something and how do I fix it? Appreciate any suggestions or help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. try to delete and reinstall "glue", then update devtools and install tune.
2. you can face issues if you don't have write access to C: and try installing packages there. Try running R or Rstudio in admin-mode. If you can't, add a second library to .libPaths using some folder where you have write-accesss.
3. Your point 4 seems to be linked to my point 2 here.

Comment: I have removed `glue` and then installed `glue`, `devtools` but when I am trying to install `tune` using `devtools::install_github("tidymodels/tune")` I am getting error: `Error: package ‘digest’ does not have a namespace`. I am also logged in as Administrator user account. One thing I have noticed is if I remove `read only` property from `R-4.0.3` folder then it still shows `read only`. Can that be a reason ?

Comment: Do you really need the latest development version of tune? An easy way to install it would be: `install.packages("tune")` . I tried installing it using `devtools::install_github("tidymodels/tune")` and I had to do the following to get it to run:

1. delete rsample and glue, reinstall from CRAN - both within a fresh R session (so restart R prior to doing so)
2. run `devtools::install_github("tidymodels/tune")` and updating all packages, including those built from source. That's so many packages, such that github refused any more requests and I had to use a VPN for downloading the rest.

Comment: I read on a stackoverflow post where julia suggested that windows user facing challenges can install `devtools::install_github("tidymodels/tune")` and ever since I have tried that I got into bigger mess. I will try again now with `install.packages("tune")` and run `tidymodels` again and if it doesn't work then I will try with `devtools::install_github("tidymodels/tune")` and the way you have suggested

Comment: Now even on reinstalling `tidymodels` with `install.packages("tidymodels", dependencies = TRUE)'` I have started to get this namespace error: `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidymodels’: package ‘digest’ does not have a namespace` on loading library: `library(tidymodels)`. I guess my last try will be to reinstall whole R & Rtudio and if it doesn't work then I will move back to `Python` than using `R`

Comment: delete digest and all dependencies and try to reinstall before installing tidymodels, that might work. I don't think it has to do with R & Rstudio in general.

Comment: now after removing `digest` I have installed tidymodels `install.packages("tidymodels", dependencies = TRUE)` and afterwards when I do `library(tidymodels)` I get `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidymodels’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘digest’`

Comment: Now again trying to install `digest` and will check the results again

Comment: finally I am able to load `tidymodels` error free and now will check if algos from tidymodels runs error free or not on windows. Thanks alot for helping me :)